# When is Big-O = x classified as inefficient?

Tags: big-o

Lets say we have a problem we implemented using X algorithm with `O(n)` or `O(log n)` or `etc...`. When is the value of `n` big enough that we must consider an alternative implementation? Let's see if i can explain myself a little better.

> **For n=10,000**
>
> O(n^2) = 100,000,000
>
> O(n) = 10,000
>
> O(Log n) = 4
>
> . . .

Obviously the best algorithm will be the one with the lowest "Big-o".

So lets say we sort an array of length 5 using bubble sort, the result is 25, that's not that bad. But when is the result of the O notation so large that realistically we must use another implementation.

Comment: Well, this is easiest question to answer, ever. It's when it is inefficient. That is, it's when it runs too slowly. I think you're discovering the difference between the theoretical efficiency compared to actual runtime of specific instances.

Comment: It's all dependent on what you're trying to do. Don't optimize something until you find out you have you.

Comment: @Noon: why didn't you put that as an answer?

Comment: "Obviously the best algorithm will be the one with the lowest 'Big-o'".  That's very often not the case.  There are other costs to consider, like memory requirements.  Algorithm A might be O(n log n) if done in-place, but only O(log n) if you can use memory proportional to n^2.  Additionally, "Big-O" isn't the whole story.  It just tells you, in broad terms, how many times you go through the critical loop.  It doesn't indicate how long each loop iteration takes.  It's possible for an O(log n) algorithm to have real-world running time that is longer than a corresponding O(n log n) algorithm.

Comment: one small comment - logs usually mean base 2, so in your estimates above O(logn) would be about 13 rather than 4.  Still, logs of different bases differ only by a constant factor and are equivalent under big O (or any asymptotic) analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it's a bottleneck in your application.

But in general, aim for algorithms with lowest complexity, while also allowing ease of implementation.

Comment: And to extend that, generally when first implementing something, *don't worry about speed*. Just implement it in the simplest way. Then if it turns out speed or complexity is a problem, refine it.

Answer (score 1):

A certain Big O complexity doesn't mean that you should always avoid it; you should shoot for algorithms of lower complexities, but O(n^2) where n is 12 is going to run plenty fast regardless of the fact that O(n^2) is usually considered a "bad" complexity.

O(n^2) doesn't automatically mean "too slow"; O(n log n) doesn't automatically mean "yay, this is fast". If a given algorithm runs too slowly, then you want to reduce its runtime, and you can often do this by reducing its complexity, but until it becomes a problem, don't sweat it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution too inefficient when there is another solution that is lower Big-O, and thus more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

When it is equivalent to [image] and alpha = 1.

Comment: using Landau's little-o notation I see?

Comment: :) any chance you can explain me what what means?